# Ad call response in ajax success contains document.write

Tags: javascript, ajax, document.write

We currently want to load an ad after an ajax load more. But that ad call response contains document.write and it is redirecting to the ad itself after the call is made. There is no method for only get the ad html and append it. So we must deal with document.write in ajax success. I saw something about iframe but don't really know how I should implement it.

```
$.ajax({
     .
     . 
     .

    success: function( response ) {
        var loadedAd = ad call here; -- but it redirects to the ad itself due to the document.write in ad response.
```

Thanks.

Comment: you should show us the response that ajax returns.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the ajax request from an iframe context should do the trick, or at least you can parse the ad result code to replace document.write calls with DOM related functions.

Example using an iframe context to evaluate ajax response:

```
var adCode = "document.write('example')",
    iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');

iframe.contentWindow.eval(adCode);
```

Comment: Should send the entire ajax request from an iframe? Or only the ad call? But how I should manage that iframe? Can you please show me a small example?